# Hadoop REST Calls

Tags: c#, .net, rest, hadoop, bigdata

I'm trying to do some basic operations of WebHDFS REST calls mainly
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#OPEN
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE

I could upload and download file, but the file is getting corrupted. I'm using .Net Code `HTTPWebRequest` and `HTTPWebResponse` for REST calls.
Content-Type is application\octet-stream.

Can any one help me to figure out how to handle this?

Comment: Use 'UTF8' formatting for file operation from HDFS to other file systems, this will solve your issue

Comment: @tom his is my code: `Stream localStream = File.Create(FileName); StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream,Encoding.UTF8); StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(localStream,Encoding.UTF8); writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd()); writer.Close(); localStream.Close(); reader.Close();` but still document files are getting corrupted